# Clarifying Griffiths syntax when solving Feynman Diagrams

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, dirac-matrices

In Griffiths textbook "Introduction to Elementary Particles", he details how to use Feynman diagrams and walks through some examples of solving some essential particle interactions. The first one he walks through is Electron-Muon scattering. He does this odd thing syntactically though that I can't figure out what exactly he is trying to convey.

[image: Griffiths Excerpt]

In his second vertex factor in the integral, he has used $\gamma^\nu$. He does this in all of the examples. As best I can tell, he is using this to differentiate the spins between particles involved in the interaction. But he then uses the Minkowski metric tensor which comes from the photon propagator to contract the indices, essentially turning the $\gamma$ matrix in the second vertex factor into it's covariant form. But at this point as you can see in the definition of the amplitude, ***M***, that he now refers to this vertex factor as $\gamma_\mu$. I can see in the wikipedia article on $\gamma$ matrices that it is standard nomenclature to switch between $\nu$ and $\mu$ when applying the metric tensor to a $\gamma$ matrix. I think this what he's saying with his statement about the space-time indices contracting, and he breifly goes on a tangent involving tensors indices in an earlier chapter, but the repeating of indices here is a little murky for me. So I just want to clarify, is this $\gamma_\mu$ still very distinct from $\gamma^\mu$ and that this is just an artifact of strict adherence to $\gamma$ matrix manipulation and a lack of unique variables? Or is the second vertex factor actually the covariant of the first vertex factor? If that is the case, then why start with $\gamma^\nu$ to begin with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you understand that the amplitude should be Lorentz-invariant? Do you understand how to construct Lorentz invariants by contracting indices? Did you learn relativistic index notation when you studied electromagnetism, or is this your first introduction to it?

Comment: I don’t think your confusion is about particle physics or Feynman diagrams, and maybe not even about Dirac matrices. Do you understand that $j\cdot j=j^\mu g_{\mu\nu} j^\nu= j^\mu j_\mu$ is Lorentz-invariant if $j$ is a four-vector under Lorentz transformations? Do you understand that the last two expressions are implied sums (one a double sum)? Do you understand that the names of the indices are irrelevant?

Comment: Note: I deliberately chose $j$ because the expressions in the square brackets are the electron’s and muon’s four-current densities.

Comment: *he is using this to differentiate the spins between particles* No. Gamma matrices do have two implied spinor indices, but the $\mu$ or $\nu$ is a *vector* index and its value identifies a component of the electron or muon’s electromagnetic four-current. Charged particles have a four-current even if they are spinless.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you for all the comments. I will try to answer your questions in order. The book had not explicitly stated that, but it does make sense given the portions that compose the amplitude. I vaguely understand the concept of contracting indices, but I do understand the use of the metric tensor and it's use in generating the invariant I = $x_\mu x^\mu$. My EM course did not cover relativity. Note: I am not reading this book for a course, just my own curiosity. You could plug j into my equation and get what you wrote in your second comment so I would say yes I get that part.

Comment: My recommendation is to put your book aside for a week and read a book, or something online, that covers special relativity, four-vectors, contravariance, covariance, invariance, metrics, relativistic index notation, etc. in a simpler context than quantum field theory. For example, go understand Maxwell’s equations using $F_{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: @G.Smith and you are just using the same $g_\mu\nu x^\nu = x_\mu$ nomenclature he is employing. And yes I get that the invariant I implies a double sum. Your comment about the indices being irrelevant is interesting though, I guess that's a problem I have when variables start to look too similar I have a hard time being able to divorce that the two are not related. I will have to go do some digging on four current densities it sounds like to fully grasp what is truly happening in these diagrams. Thanks again!

Comment: Griffiths is just using the fact that $g_{\mu \nu} \gamma^\nu = \gamma_\mu$. That's all there is to it.

Comment: @Patrick You probably know this, but just for the record $\gamma^\mu$ is not actually a four vector. But it behaves like a four vector when sandwiched between spinors, it's ok to treat it like a four vector in this context. Having said that, I agree with G. Smith that the OP should walk before running and carefully read Chapter 3 of Griffifths (or another reference covering similar material) to make sure they can handle index contractions in their sleep before moving on.

Comment: @Andrew  Yes, I know that and it is a good point to make. I should have pointed this out. I thought the OP might not be ready to get into that detail, but I think now that you are right that it is important to point out. So let me rephrase my answer to make it correct. To the OP: what Griffiths uses is  $$g_{\mu \nu}  \overline{\Psi}  \gamma^\nu \Psi = \overline{\Psi} g_{\mu \nu} \gamma^\nu \Psi = \overline{\Psi} \gamma_\mu \Psi$$ because, as Andrew pointed out, the combination $\overline{\Psi} \gamma^\nu \Psi$ is a four-vector.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I am okay with the use of the contraction. That is not my hang up. I was re-reading Ch. 3 and the parts of Ch. 7 that precede this section, and what my real issue is, is that up to this point when he's used $\gamma^\mu$ and $\gamma^\nu$ he used that nomenclature to refer to a single $\gamma$ matrix, and $\mu$ and $\nu$ were meant to differentiate that. I think in this context now, he's using $\gamma$ to mean a vector of 4x4 matrices. And so that equation for the amplitude, by use of the Einstein notation is now a sum over all the indices of those vectors.

Comment: Which is I think the point @G.Smith was making that the names of the indices are irrelevant and are chosen this way to make the math consistent with the Einstein notation, if I am interpreting this correctly that is.